# Need to highlight a row in slick grid based on some condition

Tags: jquery, salesforce, slickgrid

I have a slick grid in visual force page, I need to highlight a row based on some conditions. I am new to slick grid and i am not getting how to achieve this.

When i click on save button, If there is any error particular row should highlight. Below is my save functionality.

```
$j("#save").click(function (e) {
                 e.preventDefault();
                 $j("#save").prop("disabled",true);
                 $j.when(
                  promiseUpsertOrderData()

                ).then(function(OrderResults) {
                   if (OrderResults.errorList != null && OrderResults.errorList.length != 0 ) {
                       $errors = $j('#error');
                       $j($errors).empty();
                        $j('<ul>').appendTo($errors);
                        for (var i=0; i < OrderResults.errorList.length; i++)
                        {
                           $j("<li/>").html(OrderResults.errorList[i]).appendTo($errors);


                        }
                        $j('</ul>').appendTo($errors);
                        $errors.show();
                        $j("#save").prop("disabled",false);
                    } else { 
                       $j('#error').html('').hide();
                       if (OrderResults.warningList != null && OrderResults.warningList.length != 0 ) {
                           $errors = $j('#error');
                           $j($errors).empty();
                            $j('<ul>').appendTo($errors);
                            for (var i=0; i < OrderResults.warningList.length; i++)
                            {
                               $j("<li/>").html(OrderResults.warningList[i]).appendTo($errors);


                            }
                            $j('</ul>').appendTo($errors);
                            $errors.show();
                            $j("#save").prop("disabled",false);
                        } 
                       initializeGrid(OrderResults);
                       $j.when(
                            $j('#success').html('Save Successful').show().fadeOut(10000)
                       ).done(
                            function(){
                                $j("#save").prop("disabled",false);         
                            }
                       );

                       grid.updateRowCount();
                       grid.render();
                    }

                 });
            });
```

Can any one please help me in achieving this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually need to highlight or select a particular row on a given condition?

Comment: Need to highlight a row on a given condition. If that is not possible selecting a particular row is also fine.